# Generating an entertaining blinking pattern for a 1D LED arrangement

Tags: math, embedded, bit-manipulation, fractals

I want to actuate a hardware featuring a set of 16 LEDs, arranged in a square:

```
  X   X   X   X   X
  X               X
  X               X
  X               X
  X   X   X   X   X
```

While I can solve the technical details (timer, bit masking, etc.), I am stuck with an artistic question. 
What would be a good algorithm for generating an activation pattern (over time) which is entertaining for a human observer?

I don't want to go for a totally random pattern, but also not for something too predictive. Any suggestions, especially with compact generator algorithms are welcome.

LEDs are binary (on/off) and single color, but I could install different LEDs of single color (red,green,yellow).

Comment: A nice tail-chasing snake is always good. "look deeply into the light... you are getting sleepy... very very sleepy"

Comment: an lfsr makes an interesting pattern, not sure how it would look in a loop though.

Comment: Tagged "fractals"! You are kidding right!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some proposals:

- Wandering dots which react with each other
- More generally, cellular automata
- Simple hypnotic patterns (regular, symmetric or rotating, filling up)
- Morse code
- Random bit patterns (LFSR)

To keep it interesting you can implements several animations and switch between them.

*Full disclosure: This advice was given after a weekend at [Das Labor](http://www.das-labor.org/wiki/Projects) in Bochum.*